# Illegal char <:> at index 47: com.example.appName.app-mergeDebugResources-154:/values/values.xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, zegocloud

This error appears when trying to put these two implementations for ZegoCloud:

> implementation 'com.github.ZEGOCLOUD:zego_uikit_prebuilt_call_android:+'
> implementation 'com.github.ZEGOCLOUD:zego_uikit_signaling_plugin_android:+'

And the error is gone once the implementations are removed.

I'm trying to add voice and video call features to my application using ZegoCloud, but this error appeared.
If anyone can help, thank you.